# Have T-cell receptors been engineered on viral capsids for targeting cancerous cells?

Tags: virus, cancer, cells

As explained in the [answer of another question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/113734/could-multiplexed-crispr-disable-the-mitotic-and-meiotic-genes-of-cancerous-cell), a difficulty of cancer therapeutics is the delivery of the therapeutic to only the cancerous cells, which need to be identified among healthy cells.

The [T-cell receptor](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41392-023-01309-7) (TCR) can identify cancerous cells.

It has been noted by [Schaffer et al.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2683887/#:%7E:text=Functional%20Polypeptide%20Incorporation%20into%20Structural,viral%20particles%20(Figure%202).) that viral capsids can be engineered to incorporate parts of proteins for cellular targeting.

The range of lengths of viral capsids is [20 - 200](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7150055/) nanometers long. T-cell receptor length is around [7](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10429668/#:%7E:text=The%20T%20cell%20antigen%20receptor,(23%2D50%20nm).) nanometers long. I couldn't find the range of lengths of the normal proteins used for cellular targeting by engineering them to viral capsids.

If the size of a T-cell receptor might be about the same as the usual protein used for cellular targeting, has a T-cell receptor been engineered on a viral capsid for targeting cancerous cells with therapeutics?

A Google search for the use of T-cell receptors as receptors on viral capsids returned no relevant answers. Thank you for your consideration in advance!